# Matlab: wait for certain time for mouse click, then continue

Tags: matlab, mouseclick-event, ginput

Within my Matlab script, I want the user to have 5 seconds to answer a question by clicking any mouse button for true or no mouse click for false. If the user clicks a mouse button the script continues. If 5 seconds elapses without a mouse click, the script also continues.
Any idea's how to do this?

I tried `[x,y,MouseClick]=ginput(1);` within a `tic` `toc` loop, and record the `MouseClick` variable but the script pauses at the `ginput` until something is inputted and it waits there forever. I need it to move on after 5 seconds if there is no input.

Here's the code:

```
for i=2:26

    % display current letter
    CurrentLetter=Data{i}{RowSelect};
    letter = text (0.3, 0.5, CurrentLetter, 'fontsize', 400, 'color', 'r');
    pause(0.5);
    delete (letter); % blank screen

    % allow 5 seconds to collect mouse click
    tic;
    MouseClick=0;
    while (toc<=5);
        pause(0.1);
        [x,y,MouseClick]=ginput(1);
        if MouseClick~=0 
            break; % stop loop if a mouse click has been pressed
        end
    end
 % add up the scores and write them to an xls file
 end
```

Comment: How are you prompting users with the question?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code you are using to generate the window/figure/GUI where the user gets prompted.

Answer (score 0):

You may call `waitforbuttonpress` to wait for an input - either a mouse click or a key press. You can also register a timer beforehand, which would simulate key press event with 5 second delay. By the value returned from `waitforbuttonpress` you can tell if the user clicked a mouse button, or whether it was a key press event instead (either triggered manually by user, or automatically by timer).

```
figure();
t = timer('TimerFcn', 'java.awt.Robot().keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_SPACE);', 'StartDelay', 5);
start(t);
k = waitforbuttonpress();
if k == 0
    display('user made a mouse button click!');
else
    display('5 seconds elapsed, or user pressed a button!');
end
display('doing something...');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could work with uiwait and resume:
I just assume you have a button with a callback of sorts.

So you build the button and everthing else in the GUI and call `uiwait(gcf, 5)` afterwards.

In the button callback you do what ever you do, probably logging the answer somewhere, and at the end you call `uiresume(src.parent)`